# 600x1024 240dpi not using values-h1024dp

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I have a values folder defined for devices with the minimum height of:
h320dp
h400dp
h480dp
h800dp
h1024dp

I tested my values using 600x1024 240dpi device and it seems that it doesn't use my values from h1024dp. I also tried 600x1024 160dpi device and it doesn't use those values also..

Answer (score 0):

This is for the

**7 inch tablet:**

```
layout-sw600dp-land and layout-sw600dp-port
```

This is for the

**10 inch tablet:**

```
layout-sw720dp-land and layout-sw720dp-port
```

Comment: yes, this would work but I wonder why android doesn't point it to the h1024dp folder and I would like to be consistent with the folders